# How to extend Generic Kotlin class in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

In Kotlin I have a generic interface:

```
interface Repository<I : Comparable<I>> {
    fun findById(id: I): Mono<SomeClass>
}
```

And there is an abstract class which defines the method.

```
abstract class AbstractRepository: Repository<Int> {
    override fun findById(id: Int): Mono<SomeClass> {
       ...
    }
}
```

Then I want to extend this class in Java:

```
public class SomeRepository extends AbstractRepository {}
```

This causes the compilation error saying that SomeRepository is not abstract and does not override abstract method findById(Integer) in Repository. I understand that this is because the AbstractRepository and Repository signatures for the method are different. But how to solve the problem?

Comment: It should be `override fun findById(id: Int): Mono<SomeClass> { ...` in AbstractRepository

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected the text.

Comment: That correction may, in fact, fix your issue.  Does it?

Comment: No. There was just a mistake I had made when I tried to simplify the code for the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can override and call through to the super-class implementation that is using the unboxed `int`:

```java
public class SomeRepository extends AbstractRepository {
    
    @NotNull
    public Mono<SomeClass> findById(@NotNull Integer id) {
        return findById(id.intValue());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: It is *a* solution. It solves the problem you described (not being able to compile it). I don't know of a more concise way to do it.

Comment: There should be a way to make Java see the implementation of the method in AbstractRepository. Kotlin knows that it is the implementation.

Comment: It can see it, but it doesn’t see it as satisfying the contract because non-nullable `Kotlin.Int` is not a Java Integer. It’s and `int`.

Comment: I have the implementation of that method in AbstractRepository. I do not want to reimplement it in all of the subclasses of AbstractRepository

Comment: Another possible workaround is to define an intermediate abstract class in Java like the above code and use that as the parent of all your Java subclasses. But I suggest opening a Kotlin bug on YouTrack for the problem of abstract classes with non-nullable generic types not generating both boxed and unboxed overloads of methods. If the class is `open` instead of `abstract`, it compiles an overload with Integer instead of `int`, which satisfies the contract. Seems like this should also be the behavior for abstract classes, or at least let it be turned on with an `@Jvm` annotation.